# Washer Dryer Hookup

Tags: dryer, washing-machine

I moved into a new house and want to make sure I don't flood the place.  [image]

The spigot on the left does have water to it, I turned it on for a second only, it didn't feel hot, but maybe that wasn't long enough.  The gray hose goes to drainage. The cold water also has water in it.  The pipe directly above the spigot on the left is capped off right outside the picture.  The people living here before had a washer and dryer, so I'm assuming they made it work somehow.

Can the left spigot be treated as hot and the left cold?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If you hook up the washer and start a hot wash cycle, you will be able to feel if the valve on the left gets hot as the water gets hot. If the water doesn't get hot, start a cold cycle instead. If _that_ water comes out hot instead of cold, you can swap the connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the left is hot and the right is cold but don't take that to the bank. Put a bucket under the left spigot and run enough water to see if it gets hot. The right valve has been replaced, with a blue handle, which could mean cold water, but don't take that to the bank either. At least they replaced it with a ball valve so that'll be good for a long time. Welcome to your new house... I'm sure you'll be back here.

Comment: Thank you :) and I think you're correct.